# Solr Config File. When Import Data Give Me Error

Tags: tomcat, solr

```
    <dataConfig> 
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://Yor Ip Address:port;databaseName=TEST" user="username" password="password" /> <document> <entity name="UserData" query="select id, firstName,lastName,password from UserData"> 
<document>
 <entity name="UserData" query="select id, firstName,lastName,password from UserData">
    <field column="id" name="id" /> 
    <field column="firstName" name="firstName" /> 
    <field column="lastName" name="lastName" /> 
    <field column="password" name="password" /> 
    </entity> </document> </dataConfig>


 this is my Solr Config file for connectionf ms sql with solr when i call dataimport to solr then give me error. can u help me this is correct or not?
```

Comment: Who knows. Let's see the error you get first.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the XML you posted. There is a duplicate and incomplete document section. Make sure it looks something like this:

```
<dataConfig> 
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver:localhost:port;databaseName=TEST" user="username" password="password" />
  <document>
    <entity name="UserData" query="select id, firstName,lastName,password from UserData">
      <field column="id" name="id" /> 
      <field column="firstName" name="firstName" /> 
      <field column="lastName" name="lastName" /> 
      <field column="password" name="password" /> 
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Are you still getting errors with that? If so, what does the error message say?